# Calling custom button on VF page

Tags: visualforce, custom-button

I want to call custom button on VF page and on click of that button an alert message should pop up. i wrote a code and calling custom button in VF page

I want to include Onclick javascript to popup alert message and i want my Vf page look like custom button when i place it in page layout

Note: I am new to coding please do bear with me

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
<apex:form >
 <apex:pageBlock > 
<apex:pageBlockButtons > 
    <apex:commandlink id="Marketing" onclick="something" action="{!URLFOR($Action.Contact.Marketing_Cloud_Unsubscribe)"  value="Marketing cloud unsubscribe" onComplete="alert(Successfully Submitted);" />
</apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
```

Comment: Why don't you create a custom button with type as onclick JavaScript.

Comment: Hi @RahulSharma we want to add additional functionality, Thats why we are going for VF page

Comment: You should not use a VF page to embed inside a standard layout to be displayed as a button. Instead use custom button or links which executes some JavaScript code using [AJAX toolkit](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/apex_ajax.pdf).

Comment: Hello @RahulSharma thanks for that, and when message popup and if we click on that message, can we update custom field on click of that ok in popup

Comment: Yes thats possible. I'll try to find an example.

Comment: Thanks @RahulSharma but i only asked that question anyway, it is solved